# Looking for a complete timeline of Golarion

Tags: time, golarion

I have a lot of books now about Golarion and besides of the timeline in the Inner Sea World Guide there are many others in the books concentrating on specific races and so on.

I am looking for a complete timeline with all the informations from the official Guides and Handbooks about Golarion (no third party and no adventure path events). I have checked google but could not find anything and I have checked some books but I guess I am sure that such a thing is not published yet. Anyone who can help me here with a source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There isn't one.

The official timeline is published in the **Campaign Setting** books, which are published monthly. So the timeline is constantly changing based on specific regions (few months ago we got the timeline for Qadira for example). The general timeline can be found in the Inner Sea World Guide, and the major events can be found on the [official wiki](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Portal:History).

However, there are fan compilations, some are brief and take only major events (like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F7OMT9bstw)), others attempt to go into details (like the [unofficial wiki](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Portal:History), example: [4606 AR](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/4606_AR)).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I did not know that paizo has a fixed frequence for publishing Campaign Setting books. That is a nice info.